# How to change the location of bundled JREs in install4j?

Tags: install4j

I created the install4j install script on my laptop using the local laptop login say X. Then I joined company's domain and logged in from my account to same laptop. When I ran the script from my new login, the bundled JRE was not found. Attempts to bundle the same again failed for some reason. I then manually located the bundled JRE from C:\Users\X.install4j5\jres and copied to corresponding folder and overwrote the one that was of 0 size. Now we are moving the scripts to a build machine where builds will be made in future. Do I have to follow same procedure or I can edit the script in notepad to point to the jre stored somewhere else?
The main requirement i have is I want to keep this bundled jre in SVN folder and not in its default location of C:\Users\X.install4j5\jres. The script should take the JRE from the SVN folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a compiler variable (General Settings/Compiler Variables tab), say `myBundledJre`, whose value is the path to your JRE bundle.  Then in the Media Wizard's Bundled JRE options, select "Manual entry" from the drop down menu and choose your variable (`${compiler:myBundledJre}`) as the value.

You can use either an absolute path or a path relative to your project's `.install4j` file.  If you build via the command-line or Ant task, you can change the compiler variable using build-time arguments.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but the path I have is hardcoded i.e. c:\mydir\jres\windows-x86-1.6.0_25.tar.gz my script is in c:\mydir\scripts. Any way I can give relative path instead of hardcoded one?

Comment: You can specify a path relative to the directory where your project's .install4j file is located.  E.g., ..\jres\myjre.tar.gz if there's a jres directory above the one with your project.install4j file.  You can also set the compiler variable from the command-line if you have a build script with -VmyBundledJre=c:\mydir\jres\myjre.tar.gz.